# How does traffics of other sites happened when I have already rewrite all to 404 in apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I discovered a lot of spam traffics on my website. They are like these:

```
223.202.84.24 - - [10/Mar/2017:11:13:59 +0800] "GET http://www.che101.com/buycar/455333.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12839
47.93.80.226 - - [10/Mar/2017:11:14:39 +0800] "POST http://vv.video.qq.com/getclient HTTP/1.1" 200 1712
221.229.204.144 - - [10/Mar/2017:11:14:39 +0800] "CONNECT 115.231.141.250:8089 HTTP/1.0" 403 308
218.92.147.77 - - [10/Mar/2017:11:14:39 +0800] "POST http://www.yy.com/login/getSdkAuth?embed=true HTTP/1.1" 200 355
47.93.81.74 - - [10/Mar/2017:11:14:39 +0800] "POST http://vv.video.qq.com/getclient HTTP/1.1" 200 3845
120.27.118.235 - - [10/Mar/2017:11:14:39 +0800] "POST http://api.gifshow.com/rest/n/relation/follow?language=zh-cn&sys=ANDROID_4.4.2&did=ANDROID_C078299F8B0FB5BB&mod=ONEPLUS%28A0001%29&country_code=CN&oc=GENERIC&c=GENERIC&appver=4.47.0.1852&app=0&lat=0&ud=30971336&ver=4.47&net=WIFI&lon=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 58
123.163.21.143 - - [10/Mar/2017:11:14:39 +0800] "GET http://webim.ganji.com/index.php?op=getuserandpost&puid=2375446260 HTTP/1.1" 200 55
113.123.126.119 - - [10/Mar/2017:11:14:39 +0800] "GET http://check.ptlogin2.qq.com/check?pt_tea=1&uin=2673560062&appid=716027609&ptlang=2052&r=0.21344113419763744 HTTP/1.1" 200 119
114.216.48.233 - - [10/Mar/2017:11:14:39 +0800] "GET http://webim.ganji.com/index.php?op= HTTP/1.1" 200 42
36.250.6.59 - - [10/Mar/2017:11:14:39 +0800] "CONNECT ssl.ptlogin2.qq.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

My website is surely NOT www.che101.com, vv.video.qq.com and so on. I have noticed that the response status is `200`. It is really strange. These paths do NOT exists. A `404` response should be returned.

What is more amazing, after I rewrote all requests to 404 in apache, these traffics are still responded `200`.

Here is my Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /****
    ServerName ****.com
    ErrorDocument 404 "Sorry, page not found."
    ErrorDocument 405 "Sorry, method not allowed."

    <Directory /****/>

        Options +Includes -Indexes
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All

    </Directory>


    RewriteEngine On

    # added to deny all traffics
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD|PUT|DELETE)
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=405,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found the reason finally:

Someone enabled `proxy`!

```
ProxyRequests On
```

After I commented this line, and restarted Apache. Those traffics got `404` correctly.

The only problems are who enabled it, and who are using the proxy!